# Parse with multiple decimal separators

Tags: .net, parsing, decimal-point

According to the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,7cd4fa6e2933d235):

```
// . - Decimal point. The first '.' character
// in the format string determines the location of the decimal separator in the
// formatted value; any additional '.' characters are ignored. The actual
// character used as a the decimal separator in the output string is given by
// the NumberFormatInfo used to format the number.
```

the first decimal separator should be used, the subsequent decimal separators should be ignored. However, the following statement

```
float.Parse("1.000.000", new CultureInfo("en"))
```

throws the `FormatException` with the message "Input string was not in a correct format".

Is it a bug or intended behavior?

Comment: You're reading comments where you should be reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb.aspx): _"a string of the form:
`[ws][sign] [integral-digits[,]]integral-digits[.[fractional-digits]][e[sign]exponential-digits][ws]`"_, which mentions exactly one decimal point symbol.

Comment: That looks like intended behaviour to me. "1.000.000" simply isn't a valid number in English. It looks like it's actually a string in a locale which uses `.` as a thousands separator.

Comment: I've encountered a situation where the _same_ character was used as a _decimal separator_ and as a _thousand separator_. Windows (and the `CultureInfo` class as well) do allow it.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the item above it:

> // # - Digit placeholder. If the value being

The text you quote refers to format string used for converting *to* a string, like

```
 value.ToString("#.###.###");
```

It has no bearing on `.Parse()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

That comment is in the

```
// Format strings that do not start with an alphabetic character, or that start
// with an alphabetic character followed by a non-digit, are called
// user-defined format strings. The following table describes the formatting
// characters that are supported in user defined format strings.
```

section, so the section that speaks about the `float.ToString(...)`.